# Accessibility: YouTube Embed Code Should Have Title Attribute

Tags: html, iframe, attributes, accessibility, youtube-iframe-api

I am sure this has been brought up many times before, but here it is again. It would be really great for accessibility, if YouTube's default iframe embed code were to include a title attribute with the name of the video as the value, like so:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8dCUzOiMRy4" frameborder="0" title="The art of labeling -- A11ycasts #12" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

This would aid assistive technology users to understand the contents of the iframe source more easily. While the title attribute is generally frowned upon, it still serves a useful purpose where accessibility is concerned. Especially on iframes. See https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/

This is a common issue that is flagged in many an automated testing tool as well, so I'm sure many developers would love to see this issue addressed at the source.  Literally.

Comment: It is true that this is an issue, but since Stack Overflow is neither a bug reporting site nor a discussion forum, what exactly is your question? Are you looking for a more accessible alternative to YouTube's iframe?

Comment: Hi Christophe! Thanks for your reply! According to Google Support this is indeed the place to flag issues with the iframe. Please see https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support

Comment: Requests and issues regarding the iframe can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack Overflow is not a bug tracker

Comment: Dear Michael. We are reading your comments, but please be aware that stack overflow is for *questions*, and also google stated they would reply to *questions* here. I share your opinion on this, but I also vote to close this question, as it is simply a bug report.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a feature request for a third-party product.